# Apache Won't Start on new Xampp installation: The pipe has been ended. Child: Unable to read socket data from parent

Tags: apache, windows-8, xampp, localhost

I've just installed Xampp 1.8.1 on Windows 8. I try to start Apache and it initially turns Green, then shuts down. I check the error logs, but the error messages are Greek to me, even after googling.

Here's a screencast: http://screencast.com/t/VnSsZy6h9Wap

Here are the error messages:

```
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4676:tid 392] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4676:tid 392] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[core:notice] [pid 4676:tid 392] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4676:tid 392] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 732
[mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 732:tid 392] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : AH00404: Child: Unable to read socket data from parent
[mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 4676:tid 392] AH00427: Parent: child process exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
```

Skype is not installed. I added C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe to Windows Defender, and even disabled Windows Firewall.

Answer (score 2):

You may try two things..

one, configure apache on a different port other than what it's configured right now (may be default 80)..

second thing, you try Not to install apache as a service..if it's installed as a service you can use `sc delete [service name]` to delete the service..